# Set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ made of Cartesian product of open balls in $\mathbb{R}$ must be open

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $\vec{z}=(z_1, z_2)$ be a point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $B_{r_1}(z_1)$, $B_{r_2}(z_2)$ be open balls in $\mathbb{R}$ centered at $z_i$ with radii $r_i$ ($1\le i \le 2)$. Let $U:=\{(x_1, x_2): x_i \in B_{r_i}(z_i)\}$. Prove that $U$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

> Proof:

Let $\pi_i:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be a projection map defined by $\pi_i(\vec{x})=x_i$. Then $\pi_i(U)\subset B_{r_i}(z_i)$, thus $\underbrace{[\pi^{-1}(B_{r_1}(z_1))\cap \pi^{-1}(B_{r_2}(z_2))]}_\text{set S}\subset U$. Let $B_\varepsilon(\vec{x})\subset U$ be an open ball centered at some $\vec{x}\in U$. Then $\pi_i(B_\varepsilon(\vec{x}))\subset B_{r_i}(z_i)$. Thus $B_\varepsilon(\vec{x})\subset \pi^{-1}_i(B_{r_i}(z_i))$, which implies that $B_\varepsilon(\vec{x})\subset S$. Hence, $S=U$. But since $\pi_i$ is continuous, it pulls back open sets to open sets; and a finite intersection of open sets is also open. This implies that $U$ is open.

Please let me know if this proof is not missing some logic.

Comment: Do you mean "intersection" instead of "union" in the second-to-last sentence of your proof?

Comment: Yes, thanks, correcting.